# Proxying commands across a SSH connection

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I'd like to be able to "spoof" certain commands on my machine, actually invoking them on a remote system. For example. Whenever I run:

```
cmd options
```

I'd like the actual command to be:

```
ssh user@host cmd options
```

Ideally I'd like to have a folder called `spoof`, add it to my `PATH`, and have an executable in there called `cmd` which does the spoofing. If I have a lot of commands, this could get tedious. Anyone have ideas of a good way to go about this? Such that I can add and remove a lot of commands in the future? And, I'd like to be able to pass all the arguments exactly (or as exact as possible) and every single command I want to spoof would just have the `ssh user@host` in front of it.

The reason for this is I'm running a container (specifically `singularity`) on my machine, and there are certain commands I don't really want to containerize, but still want to run from within the container. I've found I can get the functionality I want by just appending the `ssh` in front of it. Examples are `sbatch` and `matlab` which are a pain to containerize and I'm fine with just using ssh to call them. Files that these programs use are written to a bind point so the host machine can see them just fine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script can be hardlinked under all the names of commands you wish to transparently proxy:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf -v str '%q ' "${0##*/}" "$@"
ssh host "$str"
```

- SSH combines all its arguments into a single string, which is then executed by a remote shell. To ensure that the remote arguments are identical to the local one, the values need to be *escaped*; otherwise, `somecommand "hello world"` and `somecommand "hello" "world"` can be represented identically over-the-wire.
- In an appropriately extended `printf` (including both bash and ksh implementations), `%q` is replaced with an escaped form of the corresponding value, which will be `eval`ed back to the original (literal) text by if interpreted later.
- `printf -v varname` stores the output of `printf` in a variable named `varname` without the overhead/inefficiency of a command substitutions. (In ksh93, `varname=$(printf ...)` is optimized to skip subshell overhead, so this is not necessary there).
- `$0` evaluates to `argv[0]`, which is by convention the name of the command currently being run. (This can be overridden, but you trust your users to behave reasonably... right?)
- `${0##*/}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which returns only content after the last `/` in `$0` (should it in fact contain any slashes; otherwise, the original value is used unmodified).
- `"$@"` refers to the exact argument vector passed to your script.

Comment: I'll test this out. Can you explain it a little bit please?

Comment: Preliminary tests shows this works beautifully. I'll need to test some more but for now thank you so much.

Comment: I've added explanations for all the syntax in use. Let me know if there's anything missing.

Comment: @Justin, ...btw, there *is* actually a place where where this is a little bit buggy -- `printf '%q'` can generate code that is only unescaped correctly when the remote shell matches the local one. If you're using bash locally but `/bin/sh` remotely, there's potential for some trouble when passing strings with newlines or other content `%q` escapes with `$''`. The easy fix for that is to run `bash -s` as the immediate remote command and pass script text in on stdin, but that means your remote process doesn't have access to its original stdin.

Comment: @Justin, ...it's also possible to have Python's `pipes.quote()` helper do the quoting for you in a shell-independent way; I think I've answered questions on how to do that elsewhere on this site.

Comment: I'll have to dig into this a little deeper. I have much to learn... Thanks for all your help. This is actually going to run for the same user/host. So `host` is just `$HOSTNAME` for what I'm going to use it for. It sounds strange but that's how I've gotten this to work with a container technology called `singularity`.